# Grid's automatic resizing

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction, style, grid-layouts

Imagine I have a dynamic opener that changes the number of rows. For example,

```
opg = True;
Dynamic@Grid[{
   {Item[Row@{"Show slider ", Opener[Dynamic[opg]]}, 
     Alignment -> Center], SpanFromLeft},
   If[opg, {"Slider 1", Slider[1]}, Nothing]
   }, Frame -> All, ItemSize -> {{10, 10}}]
```

[image]

As you can see, whenever I click on the opener, the grid changes size to some default automatic size. Is it possible to keep the grid size based on the maximum default size its items can have? That is, I want the following behaviour

[image]

Using `ItemSize` I can get something pretty decent, but not quite what I'm asking

```
Dynamic@Grid[{
   {Item[Row@{"Show slider ", Opener[Dynamic[opg]]}, 
     Alignment -> Center], SpanFromLeft},
   If[opg, {"Slider 1", Slider[1]}, Nothing]
   }, Frame -> All, ItemSize -> {{15, 15}}]
```

[image]

However, I'd like to keep it automatic everywhere apart from the "Show slider" item, to avoid weird spacing in the other items. How would you do it?.

Two small notes:

- Notice that the opener size changes based on the grid automatic resizing: [image]
- The slider default size is not adjusted with `ItemSize`, if this is too small, the slider gets partially hidden:

[image]

Comment: Based on the last time I've looked into something like this, I don't think there is a clean way to do this. The issue with `Grid` is that there is no way (as far as I am aware) to have a "zero-height" row where you could hide the size-giving elements. So the only other option is to precompute (via `Rasterize`) the width of the columns, or to hide the elements in the header (which might actually work). One question is of course: Does it need to be `Grid`, or would something that looks similar also work?

Comment: Odd, I don't see this behavior in 12.3.1.0 running on macOS.  The `Grid` stays the same width on my machine.

Comment: @LukasLang what alternative to `Grid` were you thinking of? I guess it could also work, as long as it's list-based.